# Calculate the surface if we know the volume and ratio of the edges

Tags: volume, surfaces, ratio

If we know that the volume of a box is 5103 cm^3 and that the ratio of the edges is a:b:c=3:7:9, how do you calculate the the surface?

Comment: What is the shape of the object?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you edit the question to make it clear, and show us what you have tried and where you are stuck you are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close. Please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the object to be a cuboid.

We have ${\rm V}= abc$

Also, using the give ratios $b= \frac {7a}{3}$ and $c=3a$.

Thus, $${\rm V}=a \times \frac{7a}{3} \times 3a=5103 \implies a^3=729 \implies a=9$$

Now you have all the edges : $a=9 \; ; b=21 \; ; c=27$.

Can you calculate the surface area of the cuboid now?

Comment: Ah I see, I understand now and yes i know now how to calculate the surface.